# Converting a GWT 1.7 project to 2.0, getting development mode to run

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to get a GWT 1.7 project to run using the new development mode. Pointing Safari (with the Development Mode plugin installed) to the given URL just shows the latest compiled version. No changes are reflected when I refresh.

A clean 'hello world' project brings up the development mode which works how the old hosted mode used to - only much better!

Is there a setting I need to change to enable development mode for this old project?

Answer (score 2):

Are you pointing to the correct url. it should be something like:

```
http://localhost:8888/<your path>?gwt.codesvr=<your local ip>:9997
```

This is for the GWT 2.0 released version. without the code after the question mark it points to the compiled version.

Comment: Yeah, URL definitely correct and SDK set to GWT 2.0. Plugin doesn't appear to work on OS X 10.4 - Firefox or Safari. Workaround until this machine is upgraded to 10.6 is to use a Windows VM - it works fine in IE. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse with the google plugin you need to "point" the plugin to the new version.
Go to the projects properties(right click onthe project) in the dialog that has opened you open the Google folder in the tree on the left and select Google Web toolkit, now you should be able to select version 2.0 in the "use specific sdk" list if the 2.0 version is not in the list add it by clicking on "configure sdk..."

Answer (score 0):

I see a similar problem - my plugin works, but doesn't display URL I should paste into browser - it's simply not there like it's should be according to this picture:

[image]

However, when I manually reconstruct URL (Hilbrand, thanks for the hint how URL should look like) then development mode starts working as a charm.

I'd still like to know why my URL doesn't show though - any ideas?